# My web host supports SVN but via SSH, will that screw up access to other repositories?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My web host supports SVN but via SSH, will that screw up access to other repositories?

meaning, I have to go to ToriesSVN | Settings | Network and then select my SSH CLient (TortoisePlink.exe).

Now will this effect me getting code from says google code or any other SVN repo?

If not, why not?

Answer (score 3):

It should only affect work on SSH-based repositories. The reason it needs an SSH client is to be able to communicate with SSH hosts. There's no need for it to use one to connect to standard hosts, so it won't affect any other repo.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the SVN client will only use the SSH client for URLs that start with `svn+ssh://`.